# Adding HTML Element from Javascript becomes commented out in the end

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

My index file is in PHP and has a div in which I would like to add an element. The reason why I don't just add to the text with JQuery is because in my case I need to do something like this in my text.

```
<h3 id="points" class="text-white"><?php echo $json_values['guilds']['858917141063401512']['members'][JAVASCRIPTVARIABLEHERE]]['points'];?></h3>
```

I need to put the javascript variable in the php statement to get the json value. The javascript variable is an ID thats acquired off a login.

I tried to use JQuery syntax such as .add, .append and regular javascript by doing document.createElement but they all end up commented

If i replace the InnerHTML with regular text it works fine, but when I put in the PHP line the h3 tag is commented when I inspect in Chrome.

**Edit**

This is what the comment looks like

```
<!--?php echo $json_values['guilds']['858917141063401512']['members']['22']]['points'];?-->
```

So upon further inspection it seems to think that the <> from the php open and close tags are comments?

Comment: PHP runs on the server. You can't insert it into HTML on the client, and it's treated as a comment by the browser.

Comment: @Barmar this statement works if i statically add the value instead of using a variable. so what should i do then

Comment: You should have PHP create a JavaScript variable containing the data you need to subscript. Then have JavaScript concatenate that into the HTML it's creating.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks i did that and now it works

Answer (score 2):

> The javascript variable is an ID thats acquired off a login.

- If you need to do it with php echo, as the variable is set when user login, you can save it into php as a `$_SESSION[]`:

  ```
    <?php 
        session_start(); 

        $_SESSION['ID'] = $_POST['LOGIN_ID'];
    ?>
  ```
- Then get the ID like this in you html page

  ```
    <?php echo $json_values['guilds']['858917141063401512']['members'][$_SESSION['ID']]['points'];?>
  ```
- Remember to start the session at the begining of your html page like this

  ```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
  ```

---

Anyway, I guess the best solution is to make an **ajax request**, and send by POST the javascript variable. Then, in the ajax success function, get the `$json_values` in the response and use **jquery** to append the data.

Comment: By off login, i meant the user info is sent on the javascript file via fetch because its logging in with an ouath system. In the end i just ended up echoing the variable value on a script in the php(html) file and using that variable on my external js file.